# xp_cmdshell stored proc in sql server

Tags: java, sql

I have mapped a server to z:

So, Im trying to disconnect this mapped drive using the xp_cmdshell stored proc from the sql server 2005 using below command

```
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', '1'
reconfigure
exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell','1'
reconfigure
exec xp_cmdshell 'net use z: /d /yes
```

Im facing an error as

```
network connection could not be found
```

But, when I'm executing the command "net use z: /d /yes" from command prompt then,its executing succesfully and the drive is getting disconnected.

please tell me what's the problem with the "xp_cmd shell" stored proc

Answer (score 0):

try this command

```
net use z: /d /y
```

also you can try this

```
 NET USE [driveletter:] /DELETE /Y
```

Comment: "If you don't want to display anything try

net use * /d /y >nul"
in your case net use z: /d /y >nul

Comment: I have tried all types like "/d /y","/delete /y","/delete /yes","/d /yes". None of them are working in the stored procedure, but thorugh cmd prompt they are working